# Best way to generate tic tac toe ascii art

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to programmatically generate ascii art for a tic tac toe game. So far I have:

```py
display = ""
for i in range(0,30):
    if i == 10 or i == 20: #If on horzontal break
        for j in range(45):
                display += "_"
        display += '\n'
    else:
        for j in range(0,45):
            if j == 15 or j == 30: #If on a vertical break
                display += "|"
            else:
                display += " "
        display += '\n
```

Which prints an empty board:

```py
"""
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |              
               |              |
_____________________________________________
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
_____________________________________________
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |

"""
```

I would now like to add an 'ascii art' representation of a O or X into the grid where the player asks. Is there a simple way i can programmatically do this?

Specifically these strings:

```
"""
        ?8888P
         `88'
    8b,_  88  _,d8
    88888SEAL88888
    8P~   88   ~?8
         ,88.
        d8888b
"""
"""
       ____
     ,' __ `.
    / ,'  `. \
    | | () | |
    \ `.__,' /
     `.____,`
"""
```

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to store all lines in a list of lists of characters, and modify those as needed. Then just loop through and print them.

Comment: So use a large 2d array, and just edit the co-ordinates of the chars that need changing?

Comment: Yep, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Thomas comment i managed to get this working so have come back to post the answer in case it helps anyone else:

```py
def putXInSquare(num):

    cross =  [[' ',' ',' ',' ','?','8','8','8','8','P',' ',' ',' ',' '],#0
              [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','`','8','8','`',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],#1
              ['8','b',',','_',' ',' ','8','8',' ',' ','_',',','d','8'],#2
              ['8','8','8','8','8','S','I','C','K','8','8','8','8','8'],#3
              ['8','P','~',' ',' ',' ','8','8',' ',' ',' ','~','?','8'],#4
              [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',',','8','8','.',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],#5
              [' ',' ',' ',' ','d','8','8','8','8','b',' ',' ',' ',' ']]#6


    if num == 1:
        iOffset = 0
        jOffset = 0
    if num == 2:
        iOffset = 0
        jOffset = 16
    if num == 3:
        iOffset = 0
        jOffset = 32
    if num == 4:
        iOffset = 9
        jOffset = 0
    if num == 5:
        iOffset = 9
        jOffset = 16
    if num == 6:
        iOffset = 9
        jOffset = 32
    if num == 7:
        iOffset = 17
        jOffset = 0
    if num == 8:
        iOffset = 17
        jOffset = 16
    if num == 9:
        iOffset = 17
        jOffset = 32

    for i in range(iOffset, iOffset + 7):
        for j in range(jOffset, jOffset + 14):
            board[i+1][j] = cross[i - iOffset][j - jOffset]
```

This will produce a cross in the given location and look like this:

```py
               |               |              
    ?8888P     |               |              
     `88`      |               |              
8b,_  88  _,d8 |               |              
88888SICK88888 |               |              
8P~   88   ~?8 |               |              
     ,88.      |               |              
    d8888b     |               |              
______________________________________________
               |               |              
               |      %%       |              
               |    %%  %%     |              
               |  %%      %%   |              
               |%%          %% |              
               |  %%      %%   |              
               |    %%  %%     |              
               |      %%       |              
______________________________________________
               |               |              
               |               |              
               |               |              
               |               |              
               |               |              
               |               |              
               |               |
```

Comment: It works, so yay! But consider a list of coordinates `[[0,0],[0,16], ...]` instead of your long list of `if`s.